# Using Jquery-waypoints in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, jquery-waypoints

Im trying to use jquery waypoints using the meteor developers group's package. I am only trying to do the simplest waypoint from the getting started docs.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
    element: document.getElementById('tester'),
    handler: function(direction) {
        alert('direction: ' + direction);
    }
});
```

When I go to localhost, it says "uncaught reference; Waypoint is not defined" but when I look in the header tag, waypoints is included and its included after jquery is?

Answer (score 1):

After receiving the same error message and after trying both packages below:

meteor add jquery-waypoints.. and
meteor add mrt:jquery-waypoints2

neither worked and I received the same message. But, I installed the below package and functions fire just fine.

```
meteor add bigu:waypoints
```

This code below works with the installed package.

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById('category-2'),
        handler: function(direction) {
            console.log('this hit');
        }
    })
```

Still couldn't figure out what was wrong with the other 'official' packages but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have not installed waypoints. If you are using meteor then you probably already have npm:

Go to the terminal and type

```
npm install waypoints
```

or if you have bower

```
bower install waypoints
```

just to make sure you have it insalled, run:

```
npm list
```

and you should see it there

Comment: hmm. I added it and it still says its an uncaught reference. any idea why that might still be? should I try to add waypoints globally?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to navigate to new page or call a function when scrolling?

Comment: call a function when scrolling

Comment: ok, I do not have much experience with waypoints but i usually use something else that always worked for me. Im not sure how your code looks but try this: $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#myDiv').is(':visible')) {
        // code to run when you have scrolled to myDiv
    }
});

Comment: uses jQuery .scroll api.

Comment: is jQuery scroll apart of core jQuery?